# Boostrap 4 and Optgroups

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, optgroup

I am attempting to put a simple select menu in my contact form. I need it to have option groups. My code works fine in codepen but is not working in my bootstrap 4 site. Here is the code:

```html
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
<select class="selectpicker" id="ressource_regions_region_id">
       
               <optgroup label="Criminal Cases">
                  <option selected>Select Case Type...</option>  
                  <option value="Misdemeanor">Misdemeanor</option>
                  <option value="Felony">Felony</option>
                  <option value="Justice of the Peace  Court">Justice of the Peace Court</option>
                  <option value="Municipal Courts">Municipal Courts</option>
                  <option value="Juvenile Court">Juvenile Court</option>
                    </optgroup>
                         
                 <optgroup label="General Cases">
                     <option value="Probate">Probate</option>
                     <option value="Living Will">Living Will</option>
                     <option value="Medical Power of Attorney">Medical Power of Attorney</option>
                     <option value="Statutory Power of Attorney">Statutory Power of Attorney</option>
                     <option value="Deed Transfer on Death">Deed Transfer on Death</option>
                     </optgroup>
                </select>
```

Is there a way to make this work with bootstrap? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post out the codes you tried in **bootstrap**.

Comment: are you adding all necessary scripts from bootstrap ?

Comment: What *specifically* is not working?

Comment: I tried your snippet after adding the CSS and JS from [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bootstrap-cdn), the JS of jQuery 3.3.1 from [the CDN](https://code.jquery.com/), and the CSS and JS of Tether from [this CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tether). The snippet still worked. What problem do you see? Or if that works for you, what is different in your code?